Rewrite url with dynamic subfolders to php handler
I'm trying to clean up my site a little bit and I am running into a bit of an issue with .htaccess rewrites with dynamic/unknown subfolders.
What i'm trying to achieve is the following
Accessing
/locations/*dynamic*/*dynamic*/files/requestedfile/

Would send it over to the following php file to retrieve the page
/locations/*dynamic*/*dynamic*/files/index.php?id=requestedfile

Additionally, how would one handle urls that don't include the trailing / at the end such as:
/locations/*dynamic*/*dynamic*/files/requestedfile

I've spent numerous hours trying to get this work, I did manage to get the blog portion of the site working as intended but that did not include dynamic/unknown sub directories.

Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained?

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! The info there solved my issue.I just wish .htaccces rewrites documentation was more readily available.

The documentation of the apache rewrite module is readily available : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Does this answer your question? Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained
